# Setting text to a layout

Tags: android, layout, text, settext

In a class, if I want to set the text to the text value of a string I have, what is the code for that?

I have:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.noFaceFive);
textView.setText(textView);
```

but setText says :

The method `setText(CharSequence)` in the type `TextView` is not applicable for the arguments `(TextView)`.

Is there a set Text to display the text of a string?  Serious mind fart on my part...Thanks!

Comment: TextView is a TextView and not a string...  you can use the getText() method to get the text within a text view as a string. Please review the Android SDK TextView reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Comment: ahhhhh...then how do I pass a string to display on an xml page?

Comment: textView.setText("This is a string");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to set the text property of textView to textView itself. setText() takes a string, so try ...

```
textView.setText("The text you want to appear");
```